# How to show a forum on a custom path?

Tags: php, drupal

By default forums are enabled on forum on my site; I want them to move to share/forum. What are the different approaches I can take for it, and which one is best?

I tried doing this with the Pathauto module, but then the breadcrumbs are showing "Home >> forum" when I would expect it to show "Home >> share >> forum."

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways, 
1) either you can use pathauto(which u used but it uses default nid to track things so thats why in breadcrumbs it's showing like that)
2) use subdomain module and shift ur forum (if ur host is supporting that)
3) use a use separate forum module like phpbb or so and put it to ur desired path and using redirect.

whichever suits u..

Comment: Sorry, none of the suggested ways for me.
I have to use default inbuilt-forum of drupal and place it on ./share/forum

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the forum pages only on share/forum, you can use the following code in a custom module.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['forum'])) {
    $items['share/forum'] = $items['forum'];
    unset($items['forum']);
  }
  if (isset($items['forum/%forum_forum'])) {
    $items['share/forum/%forum_forum'] = $items['forum/%forum_forum'];
    unset($items['forum/%forum_forum']);
  }
}
```

If you want the forums to be visible in both the old, and the new path, you can use the following code.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['share/forum'] = array(
    'title' => 'Forums', 
    'page callback' => 'forum_page', 
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'file' => 'forum.pages.inc',
  );

  $items['share/forum/%forum_forum'] = array(
    'title' => 'Forums', 
    'page callback' => 'forum_page', 
    'page arguments' => array(1), 
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'file' => 'forum.pages.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

As for the breadcrumbs, you need to implement [hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter/7), considering what reported in the documentation page.

> Implementations should take into account that menu_get_active_breadcrumb() subsequently performs the following adjustments to the active trail *after* this hook has been invoked:
>
> - The last link in $active_trail is removed, if its 'href' is identical to the 'href' of $item. This happens, because the breadcrumb normally does not contain a link to the current page.
> - The (second to) last link in $active_trail is removed, if the current $item is a MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK. This happens in order to do not show a link to the current page, when being on the path for the default local task; e.g. when being on the path node/%/view, the breadcrumb should not contain a link to node/%.